# Local Maxima or minima then $D_kf(c) = 0$ for each k

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let S be an open subset of $R^n$, and let $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a real-valued function with
finite partial derivatives $D_1 f, ... , D_n f$ on S. If $f$ has a local maximum or a local minimum
at a point $c$ in $S$, prove that $D_k f (c) = 0$ for each $k$.

I think this is trivial as if not, then $D_if(c) \neq 0 $ for some $i$, then $T_c(u_i)= f'_c(u_i)=D_if(c) \neq 0$, $u_i$ is unit vector corresponding to variable $i$ dimension. But, since local maximum or minimum at c, we must have $f'(c)= 0 $ (*my question : how do I prove this?*) so a contradiction hence $D_kf(c) = 0$ for all $k$
And apart from that, is the proof correct?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are doing after `I think this is trivial`. 
You use symbols (e.g. $T$) and $f'$ that have not been defined before.

---

Here is a hint how to prove your statement.

Let $f$ have a local minima in $c∈S$. It is very common in multidimensional calculus to break down proofs to the one-dimensional case, where results already have been proven. Therefore, we define the mapping 
$$g_i(t):=f(c+te_i),$$

for every $i=1,…,n$ and $e_i$ simply being the Cartesian basis vector.

Then $g_i$ is defined on $(-δ_i,δ_i)⊂ℝ$ and $g_i$ is differentiable.

- What do you know about the extrema of $g_i$?
- Now $g_i$ is a one dimensional function in $t$, so it should be $0$ in the extrema $t^*$: 
  $$0=g'_i(t^*)=…$$
  Hint: Use the Chain-Rule.

In the following spoiler you can find the answers.

> The function has an extrema at $t=0$, so it is $$0=g'_i(0)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}D_jf(c)δ_{ij} = D_jf(c).$$

Comment: But to use the chain rule you need total differentiability of $f$, i.e. continuity of the partial derivatives.

Comment: Uh, true. Let me think about that.

Comment: Your argument can be saved by noting $g_i'(0)=D_i f (c)$ by definition!

Comment: By $T_c$ I mean the total derivative of f at c, $f'_c(u_i) = f'(c;u_i) $ is the directional derivative at c in direction of vector $u_i$

Comment: @johndoe but this may not exist

Comment: @M.Van not even around c?

Comment: I believe if is possible to construct, for any $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, a function $f: B(a,\epsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that all partials exist and yet $f$ is not differentiable.